# Use of menu to go to another class in android

Tags: android, android-menu

I want to navigate in android using Menu function from one class to another .. how do i do it ? plz help ...here's my code :

```
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
 {

    menu.add("View Map");
     MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
     return true;

 }
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 {
     switch(item.getItemId())
     {
     case R.id.viewMap: {
         Intent in=new Intent(Service.this,Map.class);
                             startActivity(in);}
                             break;
     }          
     return true;
 }
```

I am getting these errors :

```
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aid/com.aid.Map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at com.aid.Map.onCreate(Map.java:59)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-12 21:27:01.436: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: what are you lost on? the intent you have is fine and should work as long as you have your activity declared in the manifest

Comment: why you are adding   menu.add("View Map"); when you have r.menu.menu

Comment: your problem is with adding and capturing the item clicked event or in calling the new activity?

Comment: i am getting a force close ..and my problem is wid calling the new activity...m getting a null pointer exception for the class i am calling in the intent

Comment: the map activity is working anyways...bt i wanna link it thru the menu

Answer (score 0):

You start the activity correctly but have an error in Map activity. You are getting a null pointer exception in Map.java line 59 which crashes your application. The error is pointed out by these lines:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(543): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-12 21:27:01.436:            
E/AndroidRuntime(543): at com.aid.Map.onCreate(Map.java:59) 04-12 21:27:01.436:
```

Comment: so what do i do in this case..because this class is opening wen m using a button..?

Comment: You should post your onCreate function from Map class and specify which one is line 59. Some code over there creates the crash. Using the code you posted there is no way to identify the real issue.